# How to change the text of an item in a list in a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-layout, events

I was developing an app that uses recycler view and i have to change the items text after a button is pressed. The problem is i don't know how to change the text in the xml file to another text after an event. Does any one know how?

Comment: Please share your code and everything that you have done so far, otherwise, I believe that your question will get closed for being too broad. You can also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Agreed, please take the time to ask more detailed questions if you want others to give detailed/helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

While this post is not very clear, I think that perhaps this might help:

> change the items text after a button is pressed

Without code, I am under the assumption that your button is in your item row.

1. Set click listener on the button in `onBindViewHolder()`.
2. Inside your click listener call `notifyItemChanged(position)`
3. Maintain some state to handle the logic for when to increase the text size, for instance, have a var in the on click you can flag like `shouldChangeSize = true`
4. When on `onBindViewHolder()` is called again, check this state and bind as you would usually only handle this scenario and change TextView accordingly. `textView.size = 34sp` or `textView.text = "My Text`

Comment: this is actually a pretty decent answer consider there's no code posted :D will upvote

Answer (score 0):

Let you have a list of texts which you are displaying on recycler view , so on a btn click let you want to change text of 5th item in recycler view , so just change 5th item of your list and call recycler.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: This reloads the whole adapter. Not necessary.

Comment: Change it to notifyitemchanged(position);